# Text segmentation in image receipt

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, text-segmentation

I have been looking for a way to segment text from an image, specifically an image of a receipt. The problem I'm facing is that receipts have different layouts, except they always contain a table containing product names, product prices and the amount of the product.

How should I tackle this with the use of TensorFlow?

Of course I have done some research on my own, before asking this. This is how I would tackle it:

1. Train a model to segment the receipt, so I can extract the product table.
2. Cut out the table from the image.
3. Using Tesseract OCR to get the raw text.
4. Use another model to segment the text for product name, price and amount.

[Image of receipt with highlighted segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raKha.png)

[Another image of a receipt but with a different table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF6Qt.png)